# Can't get attribute to work on a method of a class

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, methods

Putting the "self.budget" attribute on the buy method returns error 'Shopper' object has no attribute 'budget', this alsoo happense when calling the gifts list to append the additional gift bought through the buy method. As such, both the list of gifts is not adjusted, the budget remains unchanged and the quantity is not updated.

```
class Shopper():
    def __init__(self, gifts, quantity, budget):
        self.buy(gifts, quantity)
        self.budget = budget
        self.quantity=0
        self.gifts=gifts
        #list to store the gifts bought
        self.gifts=[]
        if self.budget < quantity * 100:
            self.budget = budget
            print("Insuffecient budget")
        else:
            self.gifts.extend(gifts)
            self.quantity+=quantity
            self.budget-=quantity*100


    #method for buying an additional gift at certain quantity 
    def buy(self, gift, quantit):  
        if self.budget < quantity * 100:
            self.budget = budget
            print("Insuffecient budget")
        else:
            self.gifts.extend(gift)
            self.quantity+=quantity
            self.budget-=quantity*100

#the other part prints the list of gifts bought and the budget left, and the total number of gifts bought. It workds when the buy method is is empty or is removed due to attribute errors.

#Input
    #Shopper1 = Shopper(['Toys', 'Clothes', 'Foods'], 10, 5000)
    #Shopper1.enlist("book", 1)

#Gives error, "Attribute Error: 'Shopper' object has no attribute 'budget'"".
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've named both classes the same thing, and the first definition doesn't have the 'budget' attribute.

Comment: sorry. that was a repeat, will update the code. thanks.